# How to append key value in a array in json file using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to append key value inside a existing json file.

Below is the json file I am trying to modify:

```
{
   "test": [
       { "name": "name1",       "version": "1.0.0"     },
       { "name": "name2",       "version": "2.0.0"     }
   ]
}
```

Desired output:

```
{
   "test": [
       { "name": "name1",       "version": "1.0.0"     },
       { "name": "name2",       "version": "2.0.0"     },
       { "name": "name3",       "version": "3.0.0"     },
       { "name": "name4",       "version": "4.0.0"     },
       { "name": "name5",       "version": "5.0.0"     }
   ]
}
```

I have tried the following:

```
$filePath = 'C:\Users\Desktop\test.json'
$obj = Get-Content $filePath | ConvertFrom-Json
$obj.test += [pscustomobject] {@{ name = "name3"; version = "3.0.0" }, @{ 
 name = "name4"; version = "4.0.0" }}
$obj | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content $filePath
```

This is how it's returning, I tried few different ways to format by using Depth parameter. No luck.

```
{
   "test":  [
             {
                 "name":  "name1",
                 "version":  "1.0.0"
             },
             {
                 "name":  "name2",
                 "version":  "2.0.0"
             },
             {
                 "Attributes":  "",
                 "File":  "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test\\Untitled5.ps1",
                 "IsFilter":  false,
                 "IsConfiguration":  false,
                 "Module":  null,
                 "StartPosition":  "System.Management.Automation.PSToken",
                 "DebuggerHidden":  false,
                 "Id":  "d048248b-2d2b-482f-bd71-a7d78fb02ce4",
                 "Ast":  "{@{ name = \"name3\"; version = \"3.0.0\" }, @{ 
   name = \"name4\"; version = \"4.0.0\" }}"
             }
      ]
}
```

Comment: Hi welcome to stackoverflow. Show what you’ve tried and if you’re getting some errors, surely someone can help out.

Comment: I have tried this:  $filePath = 'C:\Users\\Desktop\test.json'
$obj = Get-Content $filePath | ConvertFrom-Json
$obj.test += [pscustomobject] {@{ name = "name3"; version = "3.0.0" }, @{ name = "name4"; version = "4.0.0" }}
$obj | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content $filePath

Answer (score 0):

You can do it :

```
$filePath = 'C:\temp\foo.json' 
$obj = Get-Content $filePath | ConvertFrom-Json 
$obj.test += [pscustomobject]@{ "name" = "name3"; "version" = "3.0.0" }
$obj.test += [pscustomobject]@{ "name" = "name4"; "version" = "4.0.0" } 
$obj | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content $filePath
```

Or if you want add a dynamic list of element :

```
([pscustomobject]@{ "name" = "name3"; "version" = "3.0.0" }, [pscustomobject]@{ "name" = "name4"; "version" = "4.0.0" }) | %{
$obj.test += $_
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example. Once you have it as a PCustomObject, append more to the level you desire. In this case it's test.

```
$JSON = @'
{
   "test": [
       { "name": "name1",       "version": "1.0.0"     },
       { "name": "name2",       "version": "2.0.0"     }
   ]
}
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json

3..5 | foreach {$JSON.test += [PSCustomObject]@{name = "name$_";version = "$_.0.0"}}
```

Then convert it back to JSON.

```
$JSON | ConvertTo-Json

{
    "test":  [
                 {
                     "name":  "name1",
                     "version":  "1.0.0"
                 },
                 {
                     "name":  "name2",
                     "version":  "2.0.0"
                 },
                 {
                     "name":  "name3",
                     "version":  "3.0.0"
                 },
                 {
                     "name":  "name4",
                     "version":  "4.0.0"
                 },
                 {
                     "name":  "name5",
                     "version":  "5.0.0"
                 }
             ]
}
```